# Link integrity checking on references?

Tags: reference, plone

We customized the News Item-type and replaced the embedded image with an ExtendedReferenceField (we use a central image repository).

Is there a way to activate link integrity checking on that field so that when one tries to delete the image a warning is triggered?

(Yes, link integrity checking is enabled in @@editing-controlpanel and works just fine when I insert links and images in the content body).

Condensed code for the schemaextender field used:

```py
from zope.interface import implements
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import ISchemaExtender
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import IBrowserLayerAwareExtender
from archetypes.schemaextender.field import ExtensionField
from Products.Archetypes import atapi
from archetypes.referencebrowserwidget.widget import ReferenceBrowserWidget

class ExtendedReferenceField(ExtensionField, atapi.ReferenceField):
    """ Extention reference field. """

class ImageReferenceExtender(object):
    implements(ISchemaExtender, IBrowserLayerAwareExtender)

    layer = IPackageSpecific

    fields = [
        ExtendedReferenceField(
            name= 'imageref',
            required = False,
            multiValued=False,
            allowed_types=('Image', ),
            relationship='image',
            keepReferencesOnCopy=True,
            widget = ReferenceBrowserWidget(
                ...
                )),
    ]

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def getFields(self):
        return self.fields
```

This happens in Plone version 3.3.6 as well as 4.1.6.

Comment: This happens in both 3.3.6 as 4.1.6. The field was added with archetypes.schemaextender.

Comment: See summarized code here: [link](http://pastie.org/private/rfyxlitlwun90qs9fkedxg)

Comment: Thanks; I discovered I was wrong, actually, and link integrity does not apply to arbitrary reference fields. I'll create an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link integrity works by adding references named `isReferencing` between objects, but it only does this for HTML links within TextFields, whenever an object is modified.

To support individual reference fields, you have 2 options:

1. Add `isReferencing` relationships whenever you add your `image` relationship, remove them again when the `image` relationship is gone, using events or the extender. Link integrity will then kick in.
2. Track the removal of an `image` relationship as an integrity breach. You'd need to check if the referring object is being removed.

   Take a look at the [handlers.py module](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.linkintegrity/blob/master/plone/app/linkintegrity/handlers.py) of the `plone.app.linkintegrity` package. The `referenceRemoved` event handler is called whenever *any* Archetypes reference is deleted. It updates the `ILinkIntegrityInfo` storage, adding both source and target of a `isReferencing` relationship, and this storage is consulted when handling content object deletion.

   Create a new event handler for your `image` reference and it'll be handled in the same way; delete a referenced image and the link integrity warning will be raised:

   ```py
   from plone.app.linkintegrity.interfaces import ILinkIntegrityInfo
   from Products.Archetypes.interfaces import IReference
   from Acquisition import aq_get

   def imageReferenceRemoved(obj, event):
       assert IReference.providedBy(obj)
       assert obj is event.object # just making sure...
       if not obj.relationship == 'image':
           return
       # if the object the event was fired on doesn't have a `REQUEST` attribute
       # we can safely assume no direct user action was involved and therefore
       # never raise a link integrity exception...
       request = aq_get(obj, 'REQUEST', None)
       if not request:
           return
       storage = ILinkIntegrityInfo(request)
       storage.addBreach(obj.getSourceObject(), obj.getTargetObject())
   ```

   registered with ZCML:

   ```xml
    <configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">
    <subscriber
        for="Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IReference
             zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectRemovedEvent"
        handler=".events.imageReferenceRemoved"
        />
    </configure>
   ```

Comment: @martijn-pieters  Can you show an example of option 1?   Will this work on previously created objects?  (persistence-proof?)

Comment: @FlipMcF: this has been a while; I haven't done any Plone Archetypes development in a few years now. It won't work on previously created objects, not without an explicit process that first handles all existing image reference fields and adds in the `isReferencing` relationships. See the [event handler I linked to from the answer](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.linkintegrity/blob/master/plone/app/linkintegrity/handlers.py#L141-L153) for an example; that handles *text fields* and extracts the links, then creates the references.